# Rpxnow.com works on localhost, but not on the 'net

Tags: openid, rpxnow

I'm using OpenID for my site using the free plan with rpxnow.com. I am able to make the site work on localhost, but when I deploy, I get an "unexpected api error" exception. The root cause seems to be that the 'status' field is returning something that is not 'ok'. Does anybody have insights on this problem or a solution?

Thanks,   Jay

Answer (score 1):

Jay,

You probably need to add the domain of your live server to the "Token URL Domains" list on your RPX "Settings" page.  Just sign-in to rpxnow.com and click the settings link for your application to get to the token url domains interface.

Let me know if that works for you.

~Brian Ellin

Comment: Thanks Brian. That was one of a chain of issues that caused my problem. It looks like I got them all fixed now.